# How to redirect opt-in form to thank you page?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm trying to figure out how to redirect my opt-in form to a specific page (http://www.example.com/thanks)

Here's the code for my form:

```
<form action="http://mailer334.insty.me/subscribe" method="POST" accept-charset="utf-8">
<label for="name">Name</label><br/>
<input type="text" name="name" id="name"/>
<br/>
<label for="email">Email</label><br/>
<input type="text" name="email" id="email"/>
<br/>
<input type="hidden" name="list" value="efwefwefwefwefwef"/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit"/>
</form>
```

Right now it's just taking people to the default page for Insty.me (http://mailer359911.insty.me/subscribe) which isn't what I want it to do - it need to post information to that page to add people to my email list, but redirect to a different page thanking them and giving further instructions.

Comment: Maybe gather the data and submit it as an ajax request and redirect using js after the form is submitted. Have you watched this video from their KB? http://insty.me/client/knowledgebase.php?action=displayarticle&id=144

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a wrapper php script on your domain that receives the form info and then post to the 
third party via CURL. Then do the redirect using

`header("Location: http://www.mysite.com/thanks");`

You might be thinking on submitting the form using ajax and then redirect, but that will
be impossible because the **SAME ORIGIN POLICY** enforced by the browsers as a security rule.
You cannot run ajax request against a different domain. On a phonegap application you might
override this behavior , but on a standard web app that is intended to be open on regular browsers is not possible.

Comment: It's at a 3rd party domain name which I have no control over that page at - the autoresponder service at Insty.me

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
  if(!isset($_POST['submit'])) { 
?>

<form action="http://mailer334.insty.me/subscribe" method="POST" accept-charset="utf-8">
  <label for="name">Name</label><br/>
  <input type="text" name="name" id="name"/>
<br/>
  <label for="email">Email</label><br/>
  <input type="text" name="email" id="email"/>
<br/>
  <input type="hidden" name="list" value="efwefwefwefwefwef"/>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit"/>
</form>

<?php 
   } else { 
     include 'thanks.php';
} ?>
```